# How do I load and update a XML

Tags: c++, xml, mfc, xmllite

I have tried with [XML Lite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752872%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which is pretty good with reading and writing a new xml , but when I try to add a new element to an existing XML , I am  unable to figure out how to go about it.

Is there any other way, I can do XML operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple XML work [TinyXml](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

[Processing (Reading and Writing) an XML Document Using XmlLite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752844%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) demonstrates how to update xml file with XmlLite in a streaming manner.